# What does "in-house application" mean? How to translate it?

Tags: translation, terminology

I have problem with translating this sentence:

"Running in-house systems means that you can
leverage your existing security system for purposes of authentication, authorization, and so forth"  - from Pro C# 2010 and the .NET 4 Platform

Google translate doesn't help me with this.

I don't want to translate it to my language, but I want explanation, the best with some examples.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Software written and used within the same company.

Answer (score 8):

In-House systems means applications that have been written internally in a company.

Answer (score 3):

I think it means that if you build your own system as opposed to purchasing something, you can integrate your own login process (use single sign-on).

For example, if you purchase XYZ and WidgetCo, you have to have a separate login for each application. If you build your own, you can reference AD or whatever your login process is.

Answer (score 1):

As Clifford said, it can be software written and used within the same company, but it also means when you buy the license of an app produced by another company, and then use it on your own app servers. So you don't have a monthly subscription, you are buying the app ONCE, and start using it on your own, for as long as you need it.